# Is this sentence correct: 'what am I taught,being in my first relationship'?

Tags: grammaticality

Is *'What am I taught,being in my first relationship'* grammatically correct? Can I use it as the title for my essay?

Comment: Hello, Val. It might be grammatical, but it doesn't sound at all natural. // 'Does this sentence is correct?' indicates a level of English for which the sister site, ELL, is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make sense, but the following options sound smoother:

```
Lessons Learned from my First Relationship

What my First Relationship Taught Me

Teachings from my First Relationship
```